# Qt application has unexpected QDir::currentPath

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am using `QSettings` in my Qt application to store prefences and all was fine until I start to run it on Linux mint 19. Default location for settings file is application folder, but now it is creating in users home folder.

`QDir::currentPath()` returns home folder, if I am running application by double click, and correct executable location if I am running it from terminal. I have never seen this before. Maybe somebody knows how to fix it and run application by double click from it's own folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't depend on current working directory (returned by `QDir::currentPath()`), because that can be basically anything. Looks like your desktop environment's file manager sets current directory to home folder when you run software by double clicking, and this is generally sensible, because that is usually what user would want, when opening files from the app etc.

If I read correctly what you want, that is path to application folder to store settings in, you need [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath). But note that doing this will force you to install the application to user home folder (because you can't write to system folders like */user/local/bin*, and you shouldn't change this by changing permissions, either).

Based on comments, it seems `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` gives wrong directory, but `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()` gives correct path. If that is really the case, then take the file path, and remove the executable file from it. However, looking at [the Qt source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp.html#_ZN16QCoreApplication18applicationDirPathEv), this shouldn't be possible because `applicationDirPath()` already does just that...

---

I recommend you instead use QSettings as [documented in its basic usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#basic-usage).

Comment: If I run application by double click from file manager QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() returns users home path. And I can't find anything about Nemo file manager default run folder settings...

Comment: What does QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() return?

Comment: QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() gives correct file location. I will use this way as some hack, but there is should be some explanation of current behaviour.

Comment: If QApplicationDirPath and QApplicationFilePath give different directory, that sounds like a Qt bug. Interesting case.

Comment: @kess Quick check at Qt sources (link in edited answer) seems to indicate that applicationDirPath use applicationFilePath, so it seems really strange if they give different path for you... Must be something else funny going on!